# Spoken lines in Annie Lennox' "No More I Love You's"

Tags: lyrics, meaning

In Annie Lennox' 1995 song, [*No More I Love You's*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSkboTTTmpg), a young sounding voice (maybe Annie herself voicing a childlike voice?) says

> *They were being really crazy. We were all in the car, and you know what Mummy, everyone was being really crazy.*

I'd love to know if this is "lyrics to make you wonder" or has an actual story behind it.

Answer (score 1):

"We were all in the car" seems like very misheard lyrics. The official lyrics say "They were on the come" (referring to the monsters) and that's what it sounds like to me as well.

The song is about someone lying in their bed at night, supposedly trying to sleep but having a hard time to get over a past love and the monsters are feelings: desire, despair. Also she starts the song by "I used to be lunatic" so she is the one going crazy, hence the crazy sounding voice in that verse.

Comment: It's fascinating to hear that these are the official lyrics - thanks for that.  It's a bit "disappointing" in the sense that this doesn't sound like a phrase that a young girl would use ... it makes me wonder "can that be right, is that what is really said??"

Comment: @GreenAsJade Well "offical" as in that's what came up when clicking on the official video you linked. As for young girl... isn't it just the protagonist going crazy herself, speaking like a little girl?

Answer (score -1):

The below answers are from the two links provided below.

(The Lover Speaks about the monsters)
I used to have demons in my room at night
Desire, despair, desire, so many monsters
Oh! But now...
(I don't catch myself bouncing home
Whistling buttonhole tunes to make me cry)

[Spoken Interlude]
(And people are being real crazy
But we will only come
And you know what mommy?
Everybody was being real crazy

The monsters are crazy
There are monsters outside)

https://genius.com/Annie-lennox-no-more-i-love-yous-lyrics

https://genius.com/The-lover-speaks-no-more-i-love-yous-lyrics

Comment: It's interesting - if you search around, you find other interpretations of what those words are ("We will only come/we were overcome/They were on the come/...).     But, the question remains: is there a story behind this, or is it just words to make you think?